# Cannot mount USB (ddrescue) disk image

Tags: mount, ntfs, disk, ddrescue

I was trying to **recover some data from a faulty USB stick (NTFS)** but before i tested on another USB stick.
the Virtualbox VM detected the USB stick which was unmounted in order to make a ddrescue image.

I managed to do this once but now **it doesn't seem to work** anymore as **fdisk thinks that there are several partitions when there's only one** in the USB stick???

Anyone has any ideas/suggestions?

**Steps:**

1. Check file system of usb stick to assign the right FS when mounting
   the img
2. dd the usb stick
3. check img partition properties. This is to mount the partition with
   the appropriate offset value (starting block).
4. mount img with mount **FAILED**
5. mount img with kpartx (not familiar with this tool) **FAILED**

> **Rosa recover_disk #** fdisk -l /dev/sdb
>
> > Disk /dev/sdb: 1014 MB, 1014497280 bytes
> >     17 heads, 32 sectors/track, 3642 cylinders, total 1981440 sectors
> >     Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> >     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> >     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> >     Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18
> >
> > Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> >     /dev/sdb1   *          32     1981439      990704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>
> **Rosa recover_disk #** ddrescue /dev/sdb1 dd_resc.img
>
> > GNU ddrescue 1.17
> >     Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> >     rescued:     1014 MB,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:     704 kB/s
> >       ipos:     1014 MB,   errors:       0,    average rate:   14492 kB/s
> >       opos:     1014 MB,    time since last successful read:       0 s
> >     Finished
>
> **Rosa recover_disk #** fdisk -l dd_resc.img
>
> > Disk dd_resc.img: 1014 MB, 1014480896 bytes
> >     255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 123 cylinders, total 1981408 sectors
> >     Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> >     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> >     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> >     Disk identifier: 0x4d544f4f
> >
> > This doesn't look like a partition table
> >     Probably you selected the wrong device.
> >
> > ```
> >  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> > ```
> >
> > dd_resc.img1   ?   218137203  2138359164   960110981   70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
> >     dd_resc.img2   ?   544370800  2464669663   960149432   74  Unknown
> >     dd_resc.img3   ?   225600882   769746299   272072709   82  Linux swap / Solaris
> >     dd_resc.img4   ?  2760638474  2760690110       25818+  61  SpeedStor
> >
> > Partition table entries are not in disk order
>
> **Rosa recover_disk #** mkdir /media/ddmount
>   **Rosa recover_disk #** echo $(( 32*512 ))
>
> > 16384
>
> **Rosa recover_disk #** mount dd_resc.img /media/ddmount -o loop,offset=16384 -t ntfs
>
> > NTFS signature is missing.
> >     Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Invalid argument
> >     The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
> >     Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
> >     partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
>
> **Rosa recover_disk #** kpartx -a -v  dd_resc.img
>
> > device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p1 failed: Invalid argument
> >     create/reload failed on loop0p1
> >     add map loop0p1 (0:0): 0 1920221962 linear /dev/loop0 218137203
> >     device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p2 failed: Invalid argument
> >     create/reload failed on loop0p2
> >     add map loop0p2 (0:0): 0 1920298864 linear /dev/loop0 544370800
> >     device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p3 failed: Invalid argument
> >     create/reload failed on loop0p3
> >     add map loop0p3 (0:0): 0 544145418 linear /dev/loop0 225600882
> >     device-mapper: resume ioctl on loop0p4 failed: Invalid argument
> >     create/reload failed on loop0p4
> >     add map loop0p4 (0:0): 0 51637 linear /dev/loop0 2760638474

---- 2017-03-01 UPDATE -------

The mystery remains but i manage to mount with no offset options which is a relief but not satisfying as i don't understand why which will be helpful for future reference.

Comment: Gosh, why are code blocks formatted as quotes? o.O

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have cloned the partition `/dev/sdb1` rather than the whole drive `/dev/sdb`.

`ddrescue` is a very powerful tool to rescue what it possible to read (also difficult to read due to failing hardware). But it is dangerous (like standard `dd`), because it does what you tell it to do without questions.

So it is important to double-check and triple-check that you understand what you are doing, and that there is no typing error. Otherwise you might overwrite the family pictures or some other important data in another drive, which 'should not be involved' in the cloning and recovery processes.

- That said, it is a good idea to start by cloning the damaged drive and to do the recovery attempts on a cloned copy. And `ddrescue` is a good cloning tool.
- It is more straight-forward to clone from the damaged drive (source) to another drive of at least the same size (target) compared to what you tried (to work with an image file).

Text after the character `#` is a comment (not used).

```
sudo ddrescue source-drive target-drive log-file  # generic command line
sudo ddrescue /dev/sdx /dev/sdy sdx2sdy.log       # example
```

where **x** and **y** are drive letters, for example **b** and **c**. It is very important to get these drive letter correct (and in the right order). Otherwise you can detroy important data.

---

You can get help to identify the drives with the following commands

```
df
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
sudo parted -ls
```

The info page

```
info ddrescue
```

contains a very good tutorial. Please read it carefully before you use `ddrescue` again.

---

If only the file systems are damaged (not the memory cells or internal data management in the USB drive), you can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to clone the drive. It is installed from a PPA, and will help you identify the target drive, which will reduce the risk. `mkusb version 12` alias `dus` can be used like this,

```
dus /dev/sdx   # where x is the drive letter of the source (for example b)
```

---

Finally, see the following link for more tips about repairing a USB drive or recovering data from it,

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)